# Wrong mapping NHibernate 3.3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

Do you know where is problem with mapping file?

Eroor:
Could not compile the mapping document: NHibernateTutorial.Mapping.Character.hbm.xml

I Add all my files.

Character

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace NHibernateTutorial.Domain
{
    public class Character
    {
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual int HealthPoints { get; set; }
        public virtual int Mana { get; set; }
        public virtual string Profession { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Mapping (**Character.hbm.xml**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="NHibernateTutorial"
                   namespace="NHibernateTutorial.Domain">

  <class name="Character">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="guid" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
    <property name="HealthPoints" />
    <property name="Mana" />
    <property name="Profession" />
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Error

[image]

ConnectionString

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=RAFAL-KOMPUTER\MSSQLSERVER4;Database=rafal;Trusted_Connection=True;</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

NHibernateHelper

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using NHibernateTutorial.Domain;

namespace NHibernateTutorial
{
    public class NHibernateHelper
    {
        private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

        private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
        {
            get
            {
                if (_sessionFactory == null)
                {
                    var configuration = new Configuration();
                    configuration.Configure();
                    configuration.AddAssembly(typeof(Character).Assembly);
                    _sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
                }
                return _sessionFactory;
            }
        }

        public static ISession OpenSession()
        {
            return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }

    }
}
```

Character Repository

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NHibernateTutorial.Domain;
using NHibernate;

namespace NHibernateTutorial
{
    public class CharacterRepository
    {
        public void Add(Character newCharacter)
        {
            using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    session.Save(newCharacter);
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
        }

        public Character GetCharacterByName(string name)
        {
            using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            {
                var result = session.QueryOver<Character>().Where(x => x.Name == name).SingleOrDefault();
                return result ?? new Character();
            }
        }

        public void Update(Character newCharacter)
        {
            using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    session.Update(newCharacter);
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
        }

        public void Delete(Character newCharacter)
        {
            using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    session.Delete(newCharacter);
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Exception Details:
[image]

Comment: Please write down the inner exception message in the question :) Usually NHibernate says there what happened and, in addition, maybe this will answer the question itself!

Comment: I get only this I check twice on debug -> Could not compile the mapping document: NHibernateTutorial.Mapping.Character.hbm.xml

Comment: I doubt it. Check the excetion properties in the dialog and I'm not absolutely but near to completely sure that there's a collection of errors and reasons.

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer I add Details of exception to my post

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer What is it mean? this error?

Comment: Rafael, one suggestion: instead of posting exception screenshots, go to the Watches window in the debugger, add a watch for `$exception.ToString()`, open it, copy and paste the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See your exception details:

> Could not instantiate dialect class
>   NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect [...]

Your problem isn't with the mapping but how you specify the database server technology (RDBMS) dialect. This could be happening because various reasons:

- You're trying to use a dialect not present in your downloaded NHibernate version: *do you have the latest version (3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3...?).*
- You're specifying the dialect in the wrong place or in a wrong way.

Double-check your configuration and if you've the latest version of NHibernate!

Comment: Thanks :) yeah is working! Two days :) all my weekend :) now I can rest :) hehe

Comment: @Rafael-JuniorMVCDeveloper Yeah!!! The most stupid problems are the ones that take more time...

Answer (score 2):

Have you marked mapping file Character.hbm.xml as Embedded Resource in properties of VS?